# Internal service error on LinkedIn using the Share API?

Tags: linkedin-api

While trying to send post via the [Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api) using the code as follows. I am getting

> Internal service error status 500

#### PHP code

```
$base_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/';
$url = $base_url . 'shares';
$xml  = '<share>';
$xml .= '<comment>' . 'test'. '</comment>';
$xml .= '<content>';
$xml .= '<title>' . 'TEST' . '</title>';
$xml .= '<submitted-url>' . 'http://www.google.com' . '</submitted-url>';
$xml .= '<description>' . 'description' . '</description>';
$xml .= '</content>';
$xml .= '<visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility>';
$xml .= '</share>';
$signature = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$consumer_key = '';$consumer_secret = '';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer('my_api_key', 'my_api_secret_key', NULL);
$token = new OAuthConsumer( $oauth['oauth_token'],  $oauth['oauth_token_secret'], 1);
$request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'POST', $url, array ());
$request->sign_request($signature, $consumer, $token);
$header = $request->to_header();
$response = _linkedin_http_request($url, $header, $xml);
```

Where function has:

```
function _linkedin_http_request($url, $header, $body = NULL) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if ($body) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ($body == 'token_request') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
        }
        else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header, 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        }
    }

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

The error I am getting is as given below.

```
$response = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
  <status>500</status>
  <timestamp>1411993375587</timestamp>
  <request-id>FYVRCIMJYO</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Internal service error</message>
</error>
```

*[Handling Errors & Invalid Tokens](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens)* states that it is a server issue from LinkedIn. So should I wait for a day and then check again?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but just a problem with the LinkedIn API.

Comment: What language are you using? [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)? [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

Comment: Re: reopen - see [Brad Larson's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282993/merit-of-a-flag-category-for-it-is-a-customer-support-request/282994#282994).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when testing the LinkedIn API. Try to use another website as <submitted-url></submitted-url>.

I have also used 'http://www.google.com' and get 500 Internal service error. I changed that to 'http://www.yahoo.com', and it worked fine. I don't know exactly why that happens.