# Random Internal Service Error on Linkedin Connection API

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

This is my very first question on StackOverflow, but it's always been a very useful source for answers. So I hope someone - hopefully from the Linkedin engineer team as I was redirected here by Linkedin support - will be able to help me. I couldn't find any answer to that subject on the web (Twitter, other StackOverflow questions, and other forums).

So here is the problem : I've been using Linkedin API for two years now to display our users his/her Linkedin connections, and so far I've never had any problem with the following request generated by the simple-linkedin php library :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,public-profile-url,headline,location:(name))?start=0&count=500
```

Yet since yesterday, Linkedin started sending to some users a strange error.

```
<error>
 <status>500</status>
 <timestamp>1424451457253</timestamp>
 <request-id>HISKBDLSOA</request-id>
 <error-code>0</error-code>
 <message>Internal service error</message>
</error>
```

The error is really random, so it is really hard to reproduce.
More and more of our users get the error and it is starting to get critical for our app.

I've read a similar [thread regarding the Share API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100042/internal-service-error-on-linkedin-using-the-share-api) but not about the Connection API? Did anyone already have that error and maybe found a workaround or even better a real solution?

Thanks in advance to anyone who could give me even the beginning of an explanation about what is going on..

Comment: I'm seeing the same errors since a few days ago, about the same time as when LinkedIn announced a change in their developer program.
Here's a similar complaint:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713494/linkedin-api-sever-500-error

Comment: kind of happy to see that I'm not the only one.. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working again by reducing the number of contacts I am requesting each time from 500 to 250, and do multiple rounds until I get all the contacts.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=250&modified=updated
```

Comment: Thanks @mahboudz, really appreciate the help. I will try that and get back here to share the result.

Comment: Indeed it seems that Linkedin changed their max count parameter.. That's pretty weird that they would change this without notice to API developers.. I guess it is because of the changes in their developer program. Thank you a lot @mahboudz for this very useful answer!