# LinkedIn API - Server 500 Error

Tags: linkedin-api

We are using the LinkedIn connections API to return a list of connections for a user. A specific user has over 2000 connections and we there have to use paging to return connections past 500.

On the third call where my paging is start=800 count=500 we now get a HTTP 500 error

The request is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,public-profile-url,picture-url::(original),headline,industry)?oauth2_access_token=**token**&format=json&start=800&count=500
```

The error return is:

```json
{
 "errorCode": 0,
 "message": "Internal service error",
 "requestId": "2JBK4Q1PJV",
 "status": 500,
 "timestamp": 1424849048682
}
```

If I change the request to the previous point in the page (i.e. set start=300 and count=500 it works.

This issue has only started in the last few days and I have checked the throttling. It used to work before that.

Comment: I'm seeing the same errors since a few days ago, about the same time as when LinkedIn announced a change in their developer program.

Comment: Similar complaint:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635988/random-internal-service-error-on-linkedin-connection-api

Comment: I have a contacted LinkedIn directly (long shot). Will share what I hear.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521988/currently-calling-the-connections-api-with-the-public-profile-url-is-causing-an?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working again by reducing the number of contacts I am requesting each time from 500 to 250, and do multiple rounds until I get all the contacts.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(public-profile-url)?start=0&count=250&modified=updated
```